# How to know which BMCs are supported by OpenBMC (open source BMC)?

Tags: ipmi, supermicro, bmc

Any idea how to get list of supported BMCs for OpenBMC https://github.com/openbmc/openbmc ?

For example I have a motherboard (X8SIL-F) with *Nuvoton WPCM450 BMC*.

Comment: Just to say that I am very interested about the same subject. Supermicro BMC is..., worth replacing with anyone more open.